# How can I segment the object in the image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Below are the images that I want to segment the object by white and keep the background in black, tried many methods but can't be able to find the solution;

Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19mWGtxUZccMKtZkcqRO1rcJs2o5thRMq?usp=sharing

Here is the code:

```
def my_method(img):
    # convert to hsv
    lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
    L = lab[:, :, 0]
    A = lab[:, :, 1]
    B = lab[:, :, 2]

    # negate A
    A = (255 - A)

    # multiply negated A by B
    nAB = 255 * (A / 255) * (B / 255)
    nAB = np.clip((nAB), 0, 255)
    nAB = np.uint8(nAB)

    # threshold using inRange
    range1 = 0
    range2 = 255
    mask = cv2.inRange(nAB, range1, range2)
    mask = 255 - mask

    # apply morphology opening to mask
    kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel)
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

    # antialias mask
    mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (0, 0), sigmaX=3, sigmaY=3, borderType=cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    mask = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(mask, in_range=(127.5, 255), out_range=(0, 255))

    # put white where ever the mask is zero
    result = img.copy()
    result[mask == 0] = (255, 255, 255)

    # write result to disk
    cv2.imwrite("mask_result.jpg", mask)

    # display it
    cv2.imshow("nAB", nAB)
    cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
    cv2.imshow("result", result)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Do you have any solution for it? to segmentation targeted object perfectly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the following method;

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

h,w, c = img.shape

_, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, np.mean(img), 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
edges = cv2.dilate(cv2.Canny(thresh, 0, 255), None)

cnt = sorted(cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2], key=cv2.contourArea)[-1]
mask = np.zeros((h, w), np.uint8)
masked = cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt], -1, 255, -1)

dst = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=masked)
segmented = cv2.cvtColor(dst, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Comment: please explain why you convert between BGR and RGB and back. I'm asking because that is illogical to use here.

Comment: If the background is nearly constant color and much different from the object, then image processing can help. But when the object and background are nearly the same color, this becomes nearly impossible and may require AI/Deep Learning with training. See http://remove.bg for example